# How to parse from txt file data into a structured JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a large text file that is structured like so:

```
    2018-12-02

    Blue: 25 lux
    Green: 7 lux
    Red: 16 lux
    Blue: 25 lux
    Green: 7 lux
    Red: 16 lux
    Blue: 25 lux
    Green: 7 lux
    Red: 16 lux
    Blue: 24 lux

    .....

    avgBlue: 29.80 lux
    avgGreen: 8.40 lux
    avgRed: 19.40 lux
```

and I am having trouble parsing the file correctly as I am trying to get this format for the json file

```
{  
   "Date":{  
      "2017-11-02":[  
         {  
            "Blue":"25 lux",
            "Green":"7 lux",
            "Red":"16 lux"
         },
         {  
            "Blue":"25 lux",
            "Green":"7 lux",
            "Red":"16 lux"
         },
         {  
            "Averages":{  
               "avgBlue":"29.80 lux",
               "avgGreen":"8.40 lux",
               "avgRed":"19.40 lux"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But I am not sure how I would even go about making the script for this. Any help would be appreciated as I am not familiar with python.

Comment: Have you written any code? Even to just to open the file, read out the lines and split the them into separate strings for each field.

Answer (score 2):

We would need a LOT more information about how you want to sort/organize the data, but as far as reading it into python and saving as a .json it would look something like this:

```
import json

input_data = []
with open('MyFile.txt', 'r') as file: # rename to your file
    for line in file.readlines():
        input_data.append(line.strip())

output_data = {}

# Your code to somehow sort input_data -> output_data

with open("NewJsonFile.json", "w+") as file: 
    json.dump(file, output_data)
```

I imagine your sorting algorithms will `.split(':')` the data (this will separate a string into a list at the desired character). For instance

```
myString = "Green: 25 lux"
split_string = myString.split(":")
print(split_string)
```

> ['Green', ' 25 lux']

Notice the space before 25 lux though! However just by doing this we can now say

```
{"Green": " 25 lux"}
```

And so on and so forth! (You may want to `.strip()` the space from ' 25 lux' though)

Comment: I would want the data to be organized like the sample json file I provided, where the date is at the top of each file and every third blue input would be separated into another dict.

Comment: @Ryan0 Yeah, I'm not going to do your project for you...

Comment: @Ryan0 unless maybe you pay me lots of money :)

Comment: Haha I just need some help on where to start, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to convert your textfile into a dictionary. Converting a dict into a json file is really easy by using the `json` library, but before that we have to read in the file.

It seems like the easiest way to do it here would be with a *finite-state machine*. Essentially, read one line at a time and iteratively add on to our dict as necessary, depending on what we just read.

```
my_file = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
state = 0                           # Initialize our program's state
my_dict = {"Date": {}}              # Initialize the dict we're putting everything in
for line in my_file:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        continue                    # skip blank lines
    if state == 0:
        # we're expecting a date on this line
        current_date = line.strip()
        my_dict["Date"][current_date] = []  # Initialize this date in the dict
        state = 1
    elif state == 1:
        # we're expecting a Blue or an avgBlue
        if line.find('avg') == 0:
            # we found 'avg', so we're looking for avgBlue
            value = line.split(':')[-1].strip()  # get the string after the ':'
            my_dict["Date"][current_date].append({"Averages":{"avgBlue": value}})
            state = 4
        elif line.find('Blue') == 0:
            # we found 'Blue'
            value = line.split(':')[-1].strip() 
            my_dict["Date"][current_date].append({"Blue": value})
            state = 2
        else:
            # we start a new date or something
            ...
    elif state == 2:
        # we're expecting a Green
        value = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
        my_dict["Date"][current_date][-1]["Green"] = value
        state = 3
    elif state == 3:
        # we're expecting a Red
        value = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
        my_dict["Date"][current_date][-1]["Red"] = value
        state = 1
    elif state == 4:
        ...

my_file.close()
```

This is honestly a pretty complicated construction, but since your input file isn't in an easy-to-parse format you're probably going to be more or less limited to it. I'm not gonna implement the entire thing, and you'll probably have to rewrite most of that to work with your particular input file, but it should serve as a starting point. For what it's worth, a Finite State Machine is one of the more fundamental principles of computer science, so it's worth learning.

Once you've actually got the input in a dictionary, outputting it as json is simple:

```
import json
with open('my_json.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps(my_dict))
```